# Is Sakamoto human?

Tags: sakamoto-desu-ga

At the end of chapter 4, Sakamoto has some ambiguous dialogue:

[image]

Is he implying by this that he is not human? Or is he just stating that he finds other humans interesting?

Comment: He does have an inhumanly amount of swagger

Comment: I remember the similar thing by Izaya in "Durarara". It just shows how cool and outstanding the character is.

Answer (score 4):

To me, it's like he is trying to look at human behavior from a 3rd party point of view.

We won't really know until the mangaka makes it obvious later in the story.